# How to delete a item in list based on partial search string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, for-loop

I have a list of elements lets say

```
images = ['fcs-apple-5.5.4','gcs-banana-0.6.4','tf-2', 'mvc-grape-3.4.2']
```

basically I want to delete the item that has a sub-string `grape`, so I will pass grape as `input` and look for the item matching `grape`.
so I want to do a for loop and match and find the element and delete it.
I know how to match the element, but I do not know how to find the index and delete it because I still have to get the whole list item name.

End results I'm looking for

```
images = ['fcs-apple-5.5.4','gcs-banana-0.6.4','tf-2']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
images = ['fcs-apple-5.5.4','gcs-banana-0.6.4','tf-2', 'mvc-grape-3.4.2'] 

inp = input() # you can choose your input here e.g. 'grape'

[x for x in images if inp not in x ]

#output
['fcs-apple-5.5.4', 'gcs-banana-0.6.4', 'tf-2']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
images = ['fcs-apple-5.5.4', 'gcs-banana-0.6.4', 'tf-2', 'mvc-grape-3.4.2']
substring = "grape"

images = [image for image in images if substring not in image]
print(images)
```